# Select groups of lines in file where value of one field is the same

Tags: file, pseudocode

I'm not sure how to word this question so I'll try my best to explain it:

Lets say I have a file:

> 100001,ABC,400
>
> 100001,EFG,500
>
> 100001,ABC,500
>
> 100002,DEF,400
>
> 100002,EFG,300
>
> 100002,XYZ,1000
>
> 100002,ABC,700
>
> 100003,DEF,400
>
> 100003,EFG,300

I want to grab each row and group them together where the first value in each row is the same.  So all 100001's go together, all 100002's go together, etc.

I just need help figuring out the logic.  Don't need a specific implementation in a language.

Pseudocode is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the lines are in order by COL1.
I assume "go together" means they are concatenated into one line.

The logic with pseudocode:

```
while not EOF
    read line
    if not same group
        if not first line
            print accumulated values
        start new group
    append values
print the last group
```

In awk you can test it with the following code:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = ","; x=""; last="";}
{
    if ($1 != last) {
        if (x != "")
            print x;
        x=$1;
        last=$1;
    }
    x=x";"$2";"$3;
}
END {print x;} '
```